# Is there a performance difference between using a namespace vs explicitly calling the class from the namespace?

Tags: c#, performance

Is there any performance benefit to explicitly calling a method directly from a namespace class library rather than `using` the namespace?

Here is an example of a situation I'm referring to:

```
// using
using System.Configuration;
public class MyClass
{
    private readonly static string DBConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConn"].ConnectionString;
}
```

vs.

```
//explicit
public class MyClass
{
    private readonly static string DBConn = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConn"].ConnectionString;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there isn't any.

The compiler will convert all calls to a class to use the fully qualified name anyway.

This is easy enough to see in the produced IL, using any decompiler.

Answer (score 3):

### No.

Compiler will generates the same IL ([Intermediate Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_language)) for both codes. So, there is no performance issue on this point.

For example;

```
Console.WriteLine("Sample Code");
```

generates;

```
ldstr       "Sample Code"
call        System.Console.WriteLine
```

and

```
System.Console.WriteLine("Sample Code");
```

generates;

```
ldstr       "Sample Code"
call        System.Console.WriteLine
```

**tl dr**; the compilers converts both code to  *fully qualified class names*.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with the runtime-performance, as it is solely of significance for the compiler.
The compiler must resolve the names in order to create code. This his no impact on run-time.